# iterate multiple lists with foreach in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have arrays like these :

```
 var name = new[] { "matin", "mobin", "asghar" };
 var family = new[] { "shomaxe", "jjj", "reyhane" };
 var number = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 var age = new[] { 21, 23, 24 };
```

and I want to output them like this :

```
matin shomaxe 1 21
mobin jjj 2 23
asghar reyhane 3 24
```

how can I do that with a **foreach loop**?
and how can I do it with a **for loop**?

Comment: Here you go: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jPhcWY. This will fail with an `IndexOutOfRageException` if any of the arrays are smaller than the length of `name`, but since you didn't define handling that as a requirement this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Why not changing the data structure to a list or array of objects, structs or tuples that hold for one person each? What you have now is, let's say sub optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another strange solution in fluent style with .Zip() operator:

```
var names = new[] { "matin", "mobin", "asghar" };
var families = new[] { "shomaxe", "jjj", "reyhane" };
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var ages = new[] { 21, 23, 24 };

names
    .Zip(families, (name, family) => $"{name} {family}")
    .Zip(numbers, (res, number) => $"{res} {number}")
    .Zip(ages, (res, age) => $"{res} {age}")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

From the docs about [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) operator.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your arrays are of equal length as you posted then below should work:

**ForEach loop** will need a counter variable to keep track of the position you are in the array as opposed to the **For loop**

ForEach loop

```
        int counter = 0;
        foreach(var item in name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item}, {family[counter]}, {number[counter]}, {age[counter]}");
            counter++;
        }
```

For loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name[i]}, {family[i]}, {number[i]}, {age[i]}");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using an index you can use Zip from System.Linq to combine the lists together. Example below shows combining them into a Tuple (available from C# 7.0).

```cs
IEnumerable<(string a, string b, int c, int d)> iterable = name
    .Zip(family, (a, b) => (a, b))
    .Zip(number, (others, c) => (others.a, others.b, c))
    .Zip(age, (others, d) => (others.a, others.b, others.c, d));

foreach(var i in iterable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

// Outputs:
// (matin, shomaxe, 1, 21)
// (mobin, jjj, 2, 23)
// (asghar, reyhane, 3, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing all of your arrays are of equal size :

```cs
   for(int i=0;i<name.Length;i++){
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",name[i],family[i],number[i],age[i])
   }
```

I don't see how you can do this with a foreach however...